# Upon Link Click and setTimeout

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, I am trying to execute a function 2 seconds after a link is clicked, and wait until the function completes its execution before going to the link destination.

```
/* JavaScript */
function myFunction() { /* Block of code, with no 'return false'. */ }

<!-- HTML -->
<a onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);" href="http://www.siku-siku.com">Link</a>
```

The problem is upon click, the browser immediately goes to the link destination i.e. `myFunction` didn't have time to execute. Did I miss anything here?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to `return false` from your onclick event, to cancel the actual browser handled page load.

And since you want to follow the link (*once the function is complete*) you will need to do that through javascript. But you are using a timeout so you loose the reference to the clicked element, so we need to pass that too in the method (*if you want this logic for multiple links*)

**html**

```
<a onclick="return createTimedLink(this, myFunction, 2000);" href="http://www.siku-siku.com">Link</a>
```

**javascript**

```
function createTimedLink(element, callback, timeout){
  setTimeout( function(){callback(element);}, timeout);
  return false;
}

function myFunction(element) { 
/* Block of code, with no 'return false'. */
  window.location = element.href;
 }
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/mdkjX/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
<a onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 2000);" href="#">Link</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function myFunction(){
////your other code
///
///
window.location="http://www.siku-siku.com";//at the end

}
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3cWrH/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the default behavior for a link is a **GET request** sent by the browser. Imagine that before you register your handler, browser has registered another handler to initiate a get request (just imaginary). This is the case here. You should return false in your inline handler:

```
   onclick = '(function(){ setTimeout(yourFunction, 2000); return false;})()'
```

or more simpler:

```
   onclick = 'setTimeout(yourfunction, 2000); return false;'
```

Update:

Use this (it requires jQuery):

```
    $(function () {
        $('a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = $(this).attr('href');
            setTimeout('go("' + target + '")', 2000);
        });
    });
    function go(target) {
        console.log('2 seconds passed');
        document.location = target;
    }
```

Comment: I just tried it and the browser still immediately went to the link destination. Also, by `return false`, aren't we practically telling the browser _not_ to follow the link?