# Can I chain function calls in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute the following:

```
$('#AccountID').change(SelectAccounts);

and then (SelectProducts)
```

Is there some way I can make the function SelectProducts execute after SelectAccounts all on the same line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
$("#AccountID").change(SelectAccounts).change(SelectProducts);
```

(in jQuery, event handlers are executed in the order they're bound. `SelectAccounts` will always run before `SelectProducts`)

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different functions so you'd need to call them separately.

```
$('#AccountID').change(function () {
  SelectAccounts();
  SelectProducts();
});
```

In case you need to control the exact execution time for the second function, this discussion might be useful: [Upon Link Click and setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6608975/583539)

Answer (score 0):

use [`jQuery.Callbacks()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) added from **jQuery v1.7**

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
callbacks.add( SelectAccounts);
callbacks.add( SelectProducts );
//then use callbacks.fire() with supported flags
```