# Play animated gif on click, then perform a Symfony action

Tags: image, symfony-1.4, animated-gif

I have a page that displays people's pictures.   I have an animated gif over each picture so that when people click on it, it plays a short animation with transparency so that it looks like the person is getting slapped in the face.   Here is my line of code:

```
 <img class="slap_animation" src="/images/slap-in-the-face-still.gif" alt="" onclick='this.src="/images/slap-in-the-face.gif"' />
```

It works perfectly but I want to do more with it.   I want to make it so that when people click on it, the animation plays and on the last frame, it performs a symfony action to add +1 to the "slapcount" field.   What is the easiest way to do this?  The animation is just about 2 seconds long.

Comment: Use AJAX to send data to an action and update the slapcount. BTW - I want to see that in action :D

Comment: Is this the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608975/upon-link-click-and-settimeout

Answer (score 0):

You can make a timer that every 2 seconds will add +1 to your "slapcount". When the animation is running enable the timer and when it is not disable it.